# Requested key of a value that is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native-animatable';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar, AppState} from 'react- 
native';
import {Svg, Path} from 'react-native-svg';
import Fingerprint from 'react-native-fingerprint-android';

export default class example extends Component {
static PHASE_NORMAL = 'rgba(62, 130, 247, 1)';
static PHASE_WARN = 'rgba(255, 241, 118, 1)';
static PHASE_FAIL = 'rgba(239, 83, 80, 1)';
static PHASE_SUCCESS = 'rgba(38, 166, 154, 1)';

componentDidMount() {
    this.authenticate();

    AppState.addEventListener("change", async(state) => {
        try {
            if(state === "active" && await Fingerprint.isAuthenticationCanceled()) {
                this.authenticate()
            }
        }
        catch(z) {
            console.error(z)
        }
    })
}

state = {
    phase: 'normal',
    message: '',
    cancelled: false
}

async componentWillUnmount() {
    try {
        if(!Fingerprint.isAuthenticationCanceled()) {
            //stop listening to authentication.
            await Fingerprint.cancelAuthentication();
        }
    } catch(z) {
        console.error(z);
    }
}

async authenticate() {
    this.setState({
        phase: 'normal', 
        message: ''
    })

    try {
        // do sanity checks before starting authentication flow.
        // HIGHLY recommended in real life usage. see more on why you should do this in the readme.md
        const hardware = await Fingerprint.isHardwareDetected();
        const permission = await Fingerprint.hasPermission();
        const enrolled = await Fingerprint.hasEnrolledFingerprints();

        if (!hardware || !permission || !enrolled) {
            let message = !enrolled ? 'No fingerprints registered.' : !hardware ? 'This device doesn\'t support fingerprint scanning.' : 'App has no permission.'
            this.setState({
                phase: 'fail',
                message
            });
            return;
        }

        await Fingerprint.authenticate(warning => {
            this.setState({
                phase: 'warn',
                message: warning.message
            })
        });

        // if we got this far, it means the authentication succeeded.
        this.setState({
            phase: 'success',
            message: ''
        });

        // in real life, we'd probably do something here (process the payment, unlock the vault, whatever)
        // but this is a demo. so restart authentication.
        setTimeout(() => this.authenticate(), 3000);

    } catch (error) {
        if(error.code == Fingerprint.FINGERPRINT_ERROR_CANCELED) {
            // we don't show this error to the user.
            // we will check if the auth was cancelled & restart the flow when the appstate becomes active again.
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            phase: 'fail',
            message: error.message
        })
    }
}

getPhaseColor(): string {
    return example['PHASE_'+this.state.phase.toUpperCase()];
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View duration={1000} transition="backgroundColor"
                  style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: this.getPhaseColor()}]}>
                <View style={styles.icon}>
                    <Svg width={100} height={100} viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <Path fill={this.getPhaseColor()} d="M11.83,1.73C8.43,1.79 6.23,3.32 6.23,3.32C5.95,3.5 5.88,3.91 6.07,4.19C6.27,4.5 6.66,4.55 6.96,4.34C6.96,4.34 11.27,1.15 17.46,4.38C17.75,4.55 18.14,4.45 18.31,4.15C18.5,3.85 18.37,3.47 18.03,3.28C16.36,2.4 14.78,1.96 13.36,1.8C12.83,1.74 12.32,1.72 11.83,1.73M12.22,4.34C6.26,4.26 3.41,9.05 3.41,9.05C3.22,9.34 3.3,9.72 3.58,9.91C3.87,10.1 4.26,10 4.5,9.68C4.5,9.68 6.92,5.5 12.2,5.59C17.5,5.66 19.82,9.65 19.82,9.65C20,9.94 20.38,10.04 20.68,9.87C21,9.69 21.07,9.31 20.9,9C20.9,9 18.15,4.42 12.22,4.34M11.5,6.82C9.82,6.94 8.21,7.55 7,8.56C4.62,10.53 3.1,14.14 4.77,19C4.88,19.33 5.24,19.5 5.57,19.39C5.89,19.28 6.07,18.92 5.95,18.6V18.6C4.41,14.13 5.78,11.2 7.8,9.5C9.77,7.89 13.25,7.5 15.84,9.1C17.11,9.9 18.1,11.28 18.6,12.64C19.11,14 19.08,15.32 18.67,15.94C18.25,16.59 17.4,16.83 16.65,16.64C15.9,16.45 15.29,15.91 15.26,14.77C15.23,13.06 13.89,12 12.5,11.84C11.16,11.68 9.61,12.4 9.21,14C8.45,16.92 10.36,21.07 14.78,22.45C15.11,22.55 15.46,22.37 15.57,22.04C15.67,21.71 15.5,21.35 15.15,21.25C11.32,20.06 9.87,16.43 10.42,14.29C10.66,13.33 11.5,13 12.38,13.08C13.25,13.18 14,13.7 14,14.79C14.05,16.43 15.12,17.54 16.34,17.85C17.56,18.16 18.97,17.77 19.72,16.62C20.5,15.45 20.37,13.8 19.78,12.21C19.18,10.61 18.07,9.03 16.5,8.04C14.96,7.08 13.19,6.7 11.5,6.82M11.86,9.25V9.26C10.08,9.32 8.3,10.24 7.28,12.18C5.96,14.67 6.56,17.21 7.44,19.04C8.33,20.88 9.54,22.1 9.54,22.1C9.78,22.35 10.17,22.35 10.42,22.11C10.67,21.87 10.67,21.5 10.43,21.23C10.43,21.23 9.36,20.13 8.57,18.5C7.78,16.87 7.3,14.81 8.38,12.77C9.5,10.67 11.5,10.16 13.26,10.67C15.04,11.19 16.53,12.74 16.5,15.03C16.46,15.38 16.71,15.68 17.06,15.7C17.4,15.73 17.7,15.47 17.73,15.06C17.79,12.2 15.87,10.13 13.61,9.47C13.04,9.31 12.45,9.23 11.86,9.25M12.08,14.25C11.73,14.26 11.46,14.55 11.47,14.89C11.47,14.89 11.5,16.37 12.31,17.8C13.15,19.23 14.93,20.59 18.03,20.3C18.37,20.28 18.64,20 18.62,19.64C18.6,19.29 18.3,19.03 17.91,19.06C15.19,19.31 14.04,18.28 13.39,17.17C12.74,16.07 12.72,14.88 12.72,14.88C12.72,14.53 12.44,14.25 12.08,14.25Z"/>
                    </Svg>
                </View>

                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    {this.state.phase === 'normal' && 'Touch the fingerprint sensor.'}
                    {this.state.phase === 'warn' && 'Try again.'}
                    {this.state.phase === 'fail' && 'Authentication failed.'}
                    {this.state.phase === 'success' && 'Authentication succeeded.'}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                    {this.state.message}
                </Text>
            </View>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent={true}/>
        </View>

    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    welcome: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 26,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
        marginTop: 20
    },
    icon: {
        borderRadius: 100,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        elevation: 5
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('example', () => example);
```

When I run this code than show error [image: plese view my snapshowt]

Comment: Can you see in the error log in which file and line of your project the error arises? If it doesn't contain your file, then maybe you have not properly installed some of libraries you use.

Comment: error shown on require.js  page inside the node module above shown on screenshot

Comment: try `this['PHASE_'+this.state.phase.toUpperCase()]` instead of `example['PHASE_'+this.state.phase.toUpperCase()]`